# Generalisation of convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the function $f(\theta,\phi) = \sin \left(\theta+\phi/2\right)+\sin \left(\theta-\phi/2\right)$. Defined on the torus $(x,y) \in [-\pi,\pi]^2$ with periodic boundary conditions.

This function has the property that following any downhill (uphill) trajectory always arrive at the global minimum (maximum). This property is analogous to convex functions, however $f$ is not convex.

What property describes this feature of $f$?

Neither of the wiki definitions of pseudo-convex or quasi-convex apply to this function.

Comment: Your statement is not entirely correct. The points $(\theta,\phi) \in \{-\pi,\pi\} \times \{-\pi,0,\pi\}$ are stationary points. That is, if you start in these points, you are stuck.

Comment: @gerw point taken, gradient descent fails at these points. But the more general point remains, that there exists a local optimisation strategy that will find the global minimum with certainty. I.e. in this case an arbitrary local perturbation from the points you mention is sufficient to deal with them.

Comment: As written in my answer, there is no local minimizer besides the global minimizer. Hence, any local method will converge (up to stationary points) to the global minimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this directly applies to your function $f$, but there is a notion for convexity on Riemannian manifolds like the Torus -- it is called  [geodesic convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity).

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the presence of stationary points (or if you tweak your downhill trajectory in a way that it can avoid stationary points), then a downhill trajectory always ends in a local minimum. However, all the local minimizers (there is only one) of your function are global minimizers.